# To Remotely connect a SQL Database through Internet

Tags: remote-desktop, vpn, remote-connections

I want to connect to a remote computer though internet to connect a SQL Server database.  I tried using Teamviewer successfully.  Is there any other **free tool** which can be used in lieu of Teamviewer ?

Comment: Teamviewer connects a few hosts. What has this question to do with SQL Server, database and development?

Answer (score 0):

There are are a few options.

1)  Setup up VNC (there are a lot of free VNC implementations).  If you set it up, I would recommend setting it up using SSH or some form of encryption so you are secure.
2)  Set up a remote vpn connection.  If the remote router supports something like DDWRT you can install that and set up you can vpn in to the remote network and access the machine as if you were there locally.
3)  Set up port forwarding on the remote router so that when you connect to a specific port (default for SQL server is 1433) it forwards your request to the remote machine and then you just connect to the external IP of the remote router.
4)  Set up port forwarding for Windows remote desktop.  Basically the same as #3 except a different port and you'd use RDP to connect to the machine first instead of SQL server.

Comment: Manual work to be less, as actually I want my client program to connect to a remote sql server to update data directly.  Will VNC do that ?  A solution like VPN will do that.  Searching some free solutions now.  I may move to paid services, once the whole project takes off.

Comment: VNC will not unfortunately.  VNC will only allow you to log in to the remote machine.  However DDWRT is free and can be installed on your router to set up the vpn connection.  You can even do VPN to VPN via the DDWRT routers.  It's not a commercial solution but will get you up and running until you can get a commercial solution.

Comment: Really I don't want to make the whole system more complex.  It's for a very simple infrastructure and with people having no technical knowledge / background.  Teamviewer VPN suited us well.  Just searching an equivalent solution.  Seeems DD-WRT is linux based !  What we have here is windows based machines only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL Workbench tool for this purpose .. it's really simple ...

Just configure a new connection with the tool and you get to access the database remotely...

Answer (score -1):

Just connect directly using SQL Server authentication

Update: or use trusted connection through VPN (IPSec).
If this question involves connection to SQL Server through internet. If not, then it is not development question and does not belong to SO.